# Account object Validation rule where field can be Active/Inactive multiple times

Tags: validation, account

We want to flag up to the user if and when Volunteer status changes from Inactive to Active and vice versa the validation should work.

At the moment we did a version before the validation rule did not work again.

---

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "ACTIVE"))
NOT(ISBLANK( Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c ) 
NOT(ISBLANK(  Reason_For_Leaving__c  ) 
AND
ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "INACTIVE") 
ISBLANK( Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c ), 
ISBLANK( Reason_For_Leaving__c )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your validation rule is not syntactically valid because it is missing numerous commas and parentheses. A minimally valid version could look something like this:

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "ACTIVE")),
    NOT(ISBLANK( Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c ) && NOT(ISBLANK(  Reason_For_Leaving__c  ),
    IF(ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "INACTIVE") 
        ISBLANK( Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c ) && ISBLANK( Reason_For_Leaving__c ),
        False
    )
)
```

This would result in an error if the Leaving fields are nonblank and the Status field is Active, or if the Leaving fields are blank and the Status field is Inactive, with no action otherwise.

Remember that every `IF()` needs three parameters: the comparison, the value to result if true, and the value to result if false. You also don't typically need `IF()` statements around comparisons when you're returning a Boolean value, because you can simplify to the Booleans directly:

```
(ISPICKVAL(GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "ACTIVE") 
 && NOT(ISBLANK(Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c) 
 && NOT(ISBLANK(Reason_For_Leaving__c)))
|| 
(ISPICKVAL(GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "INACTIVE") 
 && ISBLANK(Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c)
 && ISBLANK(Reason_For_Leaving__c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are many syntactical errors in your formula. Also, I don't think there is a need to use `IF` in your formula

Your validation rule should be something like below

```
OR(
    AND (
        ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "ACTIVE"),
        NOT(ISBLANK( Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c )),
        NOT(ISBLANK(  Reason_For_Leaving__c  )) 
    ), 
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Status__c , "INACTIVE"),
        ISBLANK( Vol_BDCH_Leaving_Date__c ), 
        ISBLANK( Reason_For_Leaving__c )
    )
)
```

This above validation will throw the error when either of this conditions are met

- Status is active and leaving date and reason for leaving has any value mentioned in it
- Status is inactive and leaving date and reason for leaving is left empty.